# How to listen to an URL in kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm writing an android app in Kotlin.
I need my app to be warned when the server trigger a new event.

What is the best way to do that ?
I could contact the api (an URL) from my app every second till the api say 'ok' ? But I guess there is something cleaner...

Thanx for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FCM to push some event to your app and your app can extract data and decide to act as per instruction.
If you need something instant you cannot rely on FCM because Google itself says there can be a delay in FCM notifications, in those cases you need to either have some solution like WebSocket or can use some pubsub solution like [Pubnub](https://www.pubnub.com/)

Comment: Thank you for this answer ; that's a good start!